# Delete article after end promotion

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm a beginner in Prestashop, I'd like to modify my website. I want to delete automatically a product if the promotion end is outdated.
For the special offers (promotions), the end date is written with `$product.specific_prices.to`.

I want to delete the article where the date of this variable is equal to the current date. But I don't know how to do it... In the templates? For example :

```
{if ($smarty.now|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' <= $product.specific_prices.to) && ($product.specific_prices.to != '0000-00-00 00:00:00')}
```

With a trigger in DB?

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `Clean_End_Promotion`
    DELETE FROM products
    WHERE promo_date == NOW() //but I don't which table I can use
```

With PHP files? I don't know which way is the best.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Create a new custom PHP file (include init;config.php files to access database or write connection).

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
$sql = 'SELECT id_product FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'specific_price` WHERE to >= '.$today;
$result = Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);

Foreach ($result as $res) {
$prod = new Product($res);
$prod->delete();
}
```

I dont know I haven`t test it and I have never used delete function but check product class for more info. Product->delete should remove all data from all tables.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this.

Comment: And where can I put this file?

Comment: Just create a new PHP file in your public_html or where you want it. It will be custom PHP file but remember you must include config and init to get access to database). And you could set this new php file to cron job to check it every day. Easy and fast.